# Transforming descriptive JSON to JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, json, transformation

Given the first code snippet. It leverages the Jest framework and Supertest lib. It gets currently generated via a GUI where the user makes some selections enters some addition data and exports the JavaScript file. Testing endpoints is the only scope of the generation (hence the combination of Jest and Supertest).

Editing an exported file happens only via an external editor like VSCode. Now the request came in to be able to edit the JavaScript via both the GUI and editor like VSCode.

So the idea is to create an intermediate e.g. "descriptive" JSON file, like the second snippet below, that can be modified within both an editor and by the GUI. After that, it gets transformed into the final JavaScript code.

1. Are there other methods that would accomplish the same effect? Since an intermediate file requires "learning" a new syntax an structure.
2. Is there a library that provides such functionality?
3. Is this a known concept and if so what is it called?

```js
const app = require('./server');
const supertest = require('supertest');
const request = supertest(app);

describe('api tests', () => {
    it('gets the test endpoint', async done => {
        const response = await request.get('/test');

        expect(response.status).toBe(200);
        expect(response.body).toBe('hello world');
        done()
    });
});
```

```
{
    "descibe": {
        "description": "api tests",
        "it": {
            "description": "gets the test endpoint",
            "request": {
                "method": "get",
                "url": "/test",
                "expect": [
                    {
                        "response.status": "toBe(200)"
                    },
                    {
                        "response.body": "toBe('hello world')"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what your GUI is?

Comment: I mean... it's just a configuration file, basically, right?